# reactjs - alert message with data on it

Tags: reactjs

i have a modal form dialog to enter name (data) and when the button submit clicked i wanted it to display alert message for example: '(data) have been added to the list!' sorry if this is too dumb, i am still new to reactjs thank you

this is currently my code

```
              handleCreate = () => {

              const form = this.form;
              form.validateFields((err, values) => {
                if (err) {
                  return;
                }

                var data = this.state.data
                values.data = []
                data.push(values)
                this.setState({ data:data });
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({ visible: false });

                form.resetFields();

                alert('{data} have been added!');

              });
```

Comment: the name still displayed from the console.log its just that i dont know how to display it on the alert. i am still unfamiliar with the reactjs thank you!

Comment: can you plz post data example?

Comment: if data is simple string then use alert(this.state.data + ' have been added!'')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alert(this.state.data + 'have been added!');

this is the solution, hoping i have not understood your question wrongly

Comment: if the data is object then it will show [Object object] have been added.

Comment: @JavedShaikh In case your data is an object you can display it with `JSON.stringify(this.state.data)`

Comment: @Rondev Yes, You are right. If data is object then in that case alert will show [Object object] instead of actual string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), so you need to use backticks (`` ` ``) instead of single (`'`)  or double (`"`) quotes. Also, placeholders are preceded by a dollar sign: `${expression}`.

Lastly, if the data you are trying to display is an object, you will always see `[Object object]` unless you use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
const debugMessage = "This data has been added";
const debugData = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };

alert(`${ debugMessage }: ${ debugData }`);

alert(`${ debugMessage }: ${ JSON.stringify(debugData, null, '  ') }`);
```